# How to write attachment from attachment of an email?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am fetch the email with attachment if found attachment then forward that email to some user. I used following code to do so. When I am using below code it sends email with attachment 
but attachment has no content (blank attachment). can you suggest me where I am wrong?

```
public bool AddAttachment(System.IO.Stream sm, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment atch = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(sm, fileName);
            msg.Attachments.Add(atch);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TraceService(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return false;
    }

 ObjMail.MsgData = strBuilder.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < sMail.Attachments.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sMail.Attachments[i].Name))
                {
                    if (!sMail.Attachments[i].Name.Contains(".dat"))
                    {
                        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                        System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);
                        var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                        writer.Write(sMail.Attachments[i]);

                        ObjMail.AddAttachment(ms, sMail.Attachments[i].Name);
                    }
                }   
            }
ObjMail.SendMail();
```

Comment: what are you doing with code System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                        System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);
                        var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                        writer.Write(sMail.Attachments[i]);?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov- if an attachment found in email, I write that in memory stream and send a new email with that attachment

Comment: your code do not write stream from attachment to memorystream. Moreover, your code is not compiling cause you pass to method Write variable of type Attachment instead of string or char array. Just use CopyTo method instead of streamwriter and stream reader as i said in answer

Answer (score 0):

To attach use the following code I have used the example to attach a JPG Image

```
Attachment attach = new Attachment(id + ".jpg");
attach.Name = "WhateverName.jpg";
mail.Attachments.Add(attach);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sMail.Attachments[i].Name))
                {
                    if (!sMail.Attachments[i].Name.Contains(".dat"))
                    {
                        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                        sMail.Attachments[i].ContentStream.CopyTo(ms);

                        ObjMail.AddAttachment(ms, sMail.Attachments[i].Name);
                    }
                }
```

Or may be you can use simple:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sMail.Attachments[i].Name))
                    {
                        if (!sMail.Attachments[i].Name.Contains(".dat"))
                        { 
                           ObjMail.Add(sMail.Attachments[i]);
                        }
                    }
ObjMail.SendMail();
```